# SSL connection refused with NEED_WRAP

Tags: java, ssl, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-message-broker

Current situation. There are 2 nodes on the same internal network (let's call them Bus and Broker). The internal CA has signed a request made 2 weeks ago. This signed certificate has been inserted correctly into the Broker's "keystore" as well as the Bus's "truststore". It has been verified that both nodes' software use the appropriate stores.

When trying to setup a secure connection using JMS (or AMQP) the Bus's output is as follows:

```
TID: [] [] [2021-06-16 11:47:08,949] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkHandler} -  Exception caught by Mina {org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkHandler}
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Improper close state: Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_WRAP
```

The error on the broker side is:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkHandler} -  Exception caught by Mina but without protocol engine to handle it
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Things we've excluded so far:

- The certificate is valid, as well as it's chain (and it still before expiry date)
- The serial numbers of the entries in truststore and keystore match
- The passwords used on the software to decrypt the entries are correct
- The actual correct stores are being in use (there is another key in the store matching another service which does work)
- The keystore entry is for the exact right domain (and has 2 alternatives)
- The duplicates of the certificates were all removed from the truststore

The verification of the certificates using openssl tooling was also done. The MD5 hashes of the CRT/Key/CSR all match.

Any hint/clue is appreciated.

Comment: No one? This is beginning to look like another tumbleweed award in the making :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of support figured it out.
If not explicitly mentioned in the broker configuration for the broker profile, the broker will fallback to TLS 1.0 .
In java version 1.8.0_292 TLS 1 and 1.1 have been deprecated, resulting in an illegal protocol for communication.

It was solved by adding the following line to the broker config:

```
<sslEnabledProtocols>TLSv1.2</sslEnabledProtocols>
```

Add this in the sslConnection tag under broker.xml .